# How to give initial delay is 0 when using cron expression in spring @Schedule annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to start my schedule method when the application starts. The method will run weekly once. So that i have to use cron expression. Can you guys please help me how to give initial delay =0 in cron expression so that it will run when application starts.

Answer (score 5):

You can call your scheduler method from `PostConstruct` as below.
The method annotated by @PostConstruct is run **just after the bean is initialized**.

```
@PostConstruct
public void onStartup() {
    mySchedulerMethod();
}
```

Comment: It is fine but you need to be aware that application context will not complete initialization till this method ends. If you have long running task, make sure you run it async.